# Cannot load CDO.Message object in x86 Powershell

Tags: powershell, com

I have a problem with CDO.Message when using: `New-Object -ComObject "CDO.Message"` I receive some template for com object but not the CDO.Message. This is the object I always get:

```
Name                      MemberType Definition
----                      ---------- ----------
CreateObjRef              Method     System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef CreateObjRef(type requestedType)
Equals                    Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode               Method     int GetHashCode()
GetLifetimeService        Method     System.Object GetLifetimeService()
GetType                   Method     type GetType()
InitializeLifetimeService Method     System.Object InitializeLifetimeService()
ToString                  Method     string ToString()
```

The weird thing is that this happens only in x86 Poweshell (which I have to use for other reasons), it works properly in x64 console. This is my setup:

Windows 2008 x64 SP2
Exchange 2007 SP3
Outlook 2007

I've tried installing latest updates for everything possible but it didn't help. Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a conflicting alias or command name. Try running `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile` and see if it still happens.

On a side note: is there any reason you're using CDO.Message instead of .NET types, or the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet?

Comment: Using -NoProfile didn't help. I am using CDO.Message for message parsing, I need to parse messages downloaded via GetMail tool (get all the attachments, subject etc.) and CDO.Message is great for that. Is there something similar in .NET which I could use instead of CDO?